# Implement the same music in two android activities

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, media

I'm currently developing android app using eclipse. Basicaly I want to make two activities play the same music without re-playing. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but you could create some static MediaPlayer object that would be shared across two activites.

Also you could look at Service that would could be bind to any of those activites and would start playback and play without depending on Activites.

Comment: I see. So, I need to make one class that going to handle the sound. Then on the button for moving activity I'm going to implement pause music method and resume it when the other activity start. Will it be possible?

Comment: If you decide to use 1 Service and 2 Activities scenario, music will be played continuously by service. Activities will only order service to stop/start playback. Take a look at this project (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/FakePlayer), where one service and one activity interacts. Adding another activity that will interact can be done with ease.